# MySQL query, how to optimize it better

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have the following queries one by one executing

> delete FROM secure_dl_ipmap WHERE timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL {$days} DAY)
>
> SELECT null FROM secure_dl_ddown d WHERE d.id = id_file
>
> delete FROM secure_dl_ddown WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT i.id_file FROM secure_dl_ipmap i)

**secure_dl_ddown** table

- **id**:int(10)
- **actuallink**:text
- **pretendname**:varchar(100)
- **whoreferred**:text
- **size**:int(11)

no indexes. id, actuallink, whoreferred is primary

about 100k rows;

**secure_dl_ipmap** table

- **id**:int(10)
- **id_file**:int(10)
- **ipaddress**:varchar(15)
- **dccode**:varchar(30)
- **timestamp**:timestamp
- **refer**:text

no indexes. id & refer is set as Primary

about 100k rows;

Do you have any ideas how to change queries and if needed to index the tables?

Comment: How do You know You need to optimize? Are the queries running slow? I guess yes. Look the Internet for the EXPLAIN clause, I am sure it will answer Your question.

Comment: Because it is executed for 17 seconds. Thanks for advice I will look at the Explain clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `BTREE` index on `secure_dl_ipmap.timestamp` and a `HASH` index on `secure_dl_ddown.id`:

```
ALTER TABLE secure_dl_ipmap ADD INDEX idIdx USING BTREE (timestamp);
ALTER TABLE secure_dl_ddown ADD INDEX idIdx USING HASH (id);
```

Background is that `BTREE` indices are best used for range-queries (like your "lower than"). `HASH` indices are fast on "equal" selectors.

**EDIT**

To Speed up `DELETE` operations you may use `DELETE QUICK FROM ...` as stated [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

```
If you are going to delete many rows from a table, it might be faster 
to use DELETE QUICK followed by OPTIMIZE TABLE. 
This rebuilds the index rather than performing many index block 
merge operations.
```

**EDIT2**

Following a hint found on the same page try this:

```
DELETE secure_dl_ddown 
FROM secure_dl_ddown 
LEFT JOIN secure_dl_ipmap ON secure_dl_ddown.id=secure_dl_ipmap.id_file 
WHERE secure_dl_ipmap.id_file IS NULL
```

(to delete rows that exist in t1 that have no match in t2, use a LEFT JOIN)

Comment: Hi @Benni I will check it and let you know how it perform.

Comment: Does not help very much still the time is very big maybe a 1 sec less.

Comment: Please give us the Output of your `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/NgGUzVB7r and here is simple output:  *23425 rows deleted. (Query took 141.4568 seconds.)
delete FROM secure_dl_ddown WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT i.id_file FROM secure_dl_ipmap i) *